# anything.com/xxx to redirect to anything.com using serveralias

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect Anything.com/xxx to Anything.com using serverAlias.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 0):

If you mean redirecting the literal path /xxx to /, you can just use a RedirectPermanent directive.  Note: this will also redirect urls like /xxx2 to /2 and /xxx/yyy to //yyy.

```
RedirectPermanent /xxx http://Anything.com
```

If you are looking for something fancier like only redirecting the literal /xxx or even redirecting any path under Anything.com to http://Anything.com/ you will need mod_rewrite.  This redirects only /xxx to /:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/xxx$ /
```

If instead, you really want to squash all paths under the site to /, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/..*$ /
```

This makes any URL containing at least one character after the / to map to /.  Full docs are here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Note that `RedirectPermanent` works on path prefix basis; any path after the prefix will be automatically added to the new path.